# How to determine which files are downloaded most times from Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a bucket in Google Cloud Storage. The files are accessed by users of my Single Page App. I want to know which files are downloaded most frequently.

If possible I would like to know how many times a specific file was downloaded.

I tried Bucket Monitoring on the Google Cloud Console, but I could not find it.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47724614/8016720) to see if your question is a duplicate. From your question, I am assuming access is `allUsers`. Which cloud service are you using for your site? Sidebar: I often use HTTP 307s to redirect URLs from my site to cloud storage so that I can see access in Apache logs for certain files or directors of files. That gives me more information about who is accessing what and how.

Comment: Hello@Witek, Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Comment: I did not try it so far. It seams way to complex for such a common and simple analysis. I mean when costs for storage are high, this would be the first thing to check. What causes all the costs.

Answer (score 1):

**With the help of Cloud Audit logs**( If you have activated the audit logs on GCS, you can filter on the `storage.objects.get` API call to get the required detail.), [Usage logs & storage logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#gcloud_1) **we can get information about who is accessing your GCS resources. Once it is enabled, Access & Storage logging will create CSV files with all of the details on each access. GCS will export CSV files that contain information about all requests made to objects in those buckets. This information can be aggregated to find which files are downloaded most.**

**Follow below steps to [Set up log delivery](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#delivery) and how to enable Access & Storage logging on a bucket v** `gsutil (or) gcloud` **command line:**

1. Create a bucket for the CSV (`gsutil mb gs://my-logs-bucket`);
2. Give write permissions to the analytics account (`gsutil acl ch -g cloud-storage-analytics@google.com:W gs://my-logs-bucket`);
3. Set the default ACL of the logs bucket to something more restrictive (`gsutil defacl set project-private gs://my-logs-bucket`);
4. Enable usage logging (`gsutil logging set on -b gs://my-logs-bucket [-o log_object_prefix ] gs://example-bucket`).

Finally you can download the CSVs in `gs://my-logs-bucket`, [you can easily import those into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv). So, you can query its contents easily and analyze them, or load them into **BigQuery for analysis**.

Comment: Also refer to similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47615605) for more information.