# Understanding "GCP Bucket Data Retrieval" usage billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I'm managing a really big GCP infraestructure with hundred vms, thousand workloads and petabytes of data in different buckets.

But in the last week our "Coldline Data Retrieval" billing began to increase on an alarming rate (2Tb of data every day) on a specific bucket (aka: raw-material)

Its there any way to check what files are being accesed?
Like some gcloud commands or something like that to make a ranking of the MOST used files/buckets/etc...

Right now I have no clues how what process is reading so much of my theoretically backup files...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine which files are downloaded most times from Google Cloud Storage bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76718809/how-to-determine-which-files-are-downloaded-most-times-from-google-cloud-storage)

Comment: It does.  That is just the automated comment added for votes to close a question as a duplicate.